# Library of news articles

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a library of news articles. Each story is unique by `id`.

```
 public String getStory(String id) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = MysqlDb.getConn(dbName);

        try {
            for(Publisher p : Publishers) {
                PreparedStatement prpStmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT story FROM " + p + " WHERE id='" + id + "'");
                ResultSet rs = prpStmt.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    String story = rs.getString(1);
                    rs.close();
                    return story;
                }
                rs.close();
            }   
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Come what may (like an exception, or something), I want to make sure to release the JDBC resources used by the `Connection` and `ResultSet` objects. [Does finally always execute in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java)

1. Closing the database connection in a `finally` block makes sense, right? In the code I've looked at, I've not seen `finally` really used for anything.
2. Maybe making sure that the `ResultSet` closes is not absolutely necessary? But, the `close()` method must exist for some reason... But, in my method above, the scope is too narrow to be closed by the `finally` block. What to do? Create *another* `finally` with adequate scope for the `ResultSet`?

Comment: I sure hope `Publisher.toString()` sanitizes its output properly to prevent SQL injection when you go `"SELECT story FROM " + p...`.

Comment: The proper way to handle for id is mentioned in [@janos](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/113954/24141)'s answer. I'm actually referring to how the concatenation is done with `" ... " + p + " ... "`, as theoretically that allows for this to be `true`: `p.toString() == " publisher_table where id = '?'; TRUNCATE some_tables; --"`. So, as long as your `Publisher` class is not doing something silly for this to happen, you should be all right after taking in [@janos](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/113954/24141)'s answer.

Comment: @h.j.k. thanks. I'm reading about sql injection now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to close a `Connection` is... not doing it yourself,
but using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which is the best practice as of Java 7:

```
public String getStory(String id) throws Exception {
    try (Connection conn = MysqlDb.getConn(dbName)) {
        for (Publisher p : Publishers) {
            PreparedStatement prpStmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT story FROM " + p + " WHERE id='" + id + "'");
            ResultSet rs = prpStmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                String story = rs.getString(1);
                rs.close();
                return story;
            }
            rs.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

There are a couple of other issues in your code:

- You're not using the prepared statement properly and to its full advantage. Don't create a query string as a concatenation of variables used in the WHERE clause. Those values should be set via the prepared statement. In its current form, your query may be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.
- The inner `while` loop is not actually looping. You should replace the `while` with an `if`.
- You should use try-with-resources for the prepared statement and the result set too
- "Publishers" looks like a collection, a variable, but by the naming conventions of Java only class names should start with a capital letter. So this should be renamed to `publishers`.

With the above suggestions applied, the code becomes:

```
public String getStory(String id) throws Exception {
    try (Connection conn = MysqlDb.getConn(dbName)) {
        for (Publisher p : publishers) {
            String sql = "SELECT story FROM " + p + " WHERE id = ?";
            try (PreparedStatement prpStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                prpStmt.setString(1, id);
                try (ResultSet rs = prpStmt.executeQuery()) {
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        return rs.getString(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```